# Vue JS - Remove an object from the data array

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I am using VueJS to display active users in a site. When a user becomes active, Pusher sends JSON with their details -

```
{
      "token": "97LbfNs7pfPbzVLo",
      "first_name": "Joe",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "avatar": "http://demo.com/avatar.jpg",
      "phone": "255-255-2555",
      "available" : true,
      "agencies": [
        {
          "name": "Some company",
          "slug": "some-company"
        }
      ]
    }
```

When the user signs out, their `token` is sent along with `available: false`. I need to then remove them from my Vue `data` array, this is where I am stuck.

Here is the Data array in my Vue JS (pretty basic):

```
data: {
      responders: []
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a very basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, only from outside of the Vue `methods`. Basically I just need to remove an item from the data array, I think this is more of a Javascript related issue more than it is specific to Vue.

@michaelsnowden made the suggestion to store users as objects instead of an array but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I have attempted:

```
addUser: function() {
            var user = {'asdasdasdop': {name: "Joe"}};
            this.users.push(user);
        }
```

Which gives me:

```
"users": [
    {
      "asdasdasdop": {
        "name": "Joe"
      }
    }
  ],
```

But beyond this I cannot figure out how to access these values or remove an item from the array based on the token. Any help would be greatly appreciated - I've had no issues adding but cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove something.

Comment: Is the token ID the same for becoming active/inactive?

Comment: Yes, same token for both - the token is how I was previously removing the user with plain jQuery

Comment: I feel like you didn't supply enough code or describe it well enough for me to give you a good answer. Here is a fiddle that may help some: http://jsfiddle.net/qm8csjv9/1/ And here is a fiddle where you can do it "from outside of the Vue methods" http://jsfiddle.net/qm8csjv9

Answer (score 2):

Vue augments watched arrays with a $remove method that takes the numerical index as parameter. So you can find the index with something like:

```
var userToken ='potato';
var tokenToRemove;
users.forEach(function(user, index) {
    if(userToken === user.token) {
         tokenToRemove = index;
    }
});

users.$remove(tokenToRemove);
```

so you would find in any way you can the index of the user with the token potato , and with that use the $remove method.

Comment: **Incorrect** (at least for 1.0+),

`$remove`'s only argument is the item to remove, not the index 

http://vuejs.org/api/#array-remove-reference

Answer (score 2):

```
// hook into pusher    
ready: () => {
      var self = this;
      socket.bind('new-user', (user) => {
        self.addUser(user)
      })
},
methods: {
    addUser: (user) => {
        this.users.push(user)
    },
    deleteUserByToken: (token) => {
        var user = this.findByToken(token);
        if (user != 'undefined') {
            this.users.$remove(user);
        } else { 
            // 
        }
    },
    findByToken: (token) => {
        this.users.find((usr) => {
           return usr.token === token
        });
    }
}
```

API Reference

- [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.prototype.$remove](http://vuejs.org/api/#array-remove-reference)
- [Array.prototype.$set](http://vuejs.org/api/#array-set-index-value)

[List rendering documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html)

Answer (score 1):

In vue 2.x.x, `Array.prototype.$remove` has been [removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Array-prototype-remove-removed), You can use `splice` instead as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41374441/1610034) with vue 2.

once you find out the `index`, where you want to delete an item, you can simply use:

```
this.users.splice(index, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your users in an object, instead of an array.

When a user signs in,
users[user.token] = user

When a user signs out,
users[user.token] = undefined

Comment: I thought that Vue transformed the `$data` entries into objects? I'm using `vm.$data.push(jsonData)` to add users to the list

Comment: If you could expand on this a bit further I'd really appreciate it.. I have attempted this but cannot figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question with an attempt to understand what you're suggesting, I'd really appreciate any other information you can provide. Thanks!