# How to add and remove item from array in components in Vue 2

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I made a component "my-item" which contains three elements: a dropdown (populated by "itemList") and two input boxes populated from the dropdown.
This component is considered a row.

I am trying to add and delete one row at a time but two things i am not sure about.
(1) what to add to the rows array?
(2) why is this.rows.splice(index,1) removing only the last row?

https://jsbin.com/mugunum/edit?html,output

Thanks

```
<div id="app">
    <my-item v-for="(row, index) in rows"
         :itemdata="itemList"
          v-on:remove="removeRow(index)">
    </my-item>
<div>
    <button @click="addRow"> Add Row </button>
</div>
</div>

<template id="item-template">
<div>
    <select v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="item in itemdata"  :value="item">
           {{ item.code }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text" v-model="selected.description">
    <input type="text" placeholder="value" v-model="selected.unitprice">
    <button v-on:click= "remove"> X </button>
</div>
</template>

Vue.component('my-item', {
props: ['itemdata'],
template: '#item-template',
data: function () {
    return {
    selected: this.itemdata[0]
    }
},
methods: {
    remove() {
        this.$emit('remove');
    }
}
}),

new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    rows: [],
    itemList: [
        { code: 'Select an Item', description: '', unitprice: ''},
        { code: 'One', description: 'Item A', unitprice: '10'},
        { code: 'Two', description: 'Item B', unitprice: '22'},
        { code: 'Three', description: 'Item C', unitprice: '56'}
    ]
},

methods: {
    addRow(){
       this.rows.push(''); // what to push unto the rows array?
    },
    removeRow(index){
       this.rows.splice(index,1); // why is this removing only the last row?
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are few mistakes you are doing:

1. You need to add proper object in the array in `addRow` method
2. You can use `splice` method to [remove an element from an array](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Array-prototype-remove-removed) at particular index.
3. You need to pass the current row as prop to `my-item` component, where this can be modified.

You can see working code [here](https://jsbin.com/bomavadune/1/edit?html,console,output).

```
addRow(){
   this.rows.push({description: '', unitprice: '' , code: ''}); // what to push unto the rows array?
},
removeRow(index){
   this. itemList.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Comment: @Pyol7 You are not pushing anything in the rows, you have to first fix adding rows properly, than you will know the difference on which index you are removing.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know how to fix addRow

Comment: Do I have to push the row component unto the rows array? and if so how?

Comment: @Pyol7 check [this](https://jsbin.com/bomavadune/1/edit?html,console,output) and edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, Its working but there is a lot of duplication. There must be a better way. I cleaned it up a bit but still not satisfied.

Comment: @Pyol7  this seems good, I will suggest to use codereview.stackexchange.com for this purpose, post a link here, after asking there.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Array.push()` for appending elements to an array.

For deleting, it is best to use `this.$delete(array, index)` for reactive objects.

> **`Vue.delete( target, key )`:** Delete a property on an object. If the object is reactive, ensure the deletion triggers view updates. This is primarily used to get around the limitation that Vue cannot detect property deletions, but you should rarely need to use it.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046332/how-to-remove-an-item-from-an-array-in-vue-js