# How to remove an item from an array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js (2) and I am currently working on a simple event app. I've managed to add events but now I would like to delete events based on clicking on a button.

HTML

```
    <div class="list-group">

        <div class="list-group-item" v-for="event in events">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                {{ event.name }}
            </h4>

            <h5>
                {{ event.date }}
            </h5>

            <p class="list-group-item-text" v-if="event.description">{{ event.description }}</p>

            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" @click="deleteEvent(event)">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS(Vue)

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        events: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Event 1',
                description: 'Just some lorem ipsum',
                date: '2015-09-10'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Event 2',
                description: 'Just another lorem ipsum',
                date: '2015-10-02'
            }
        ],

        event: { name: '', description: '', date: '' }
    },

    ready: function() {

    },

    methods: {

        deleteEvent: function(event) {
                this.events.splice(this.event);
        },

        // Adds an event to the existing events array
        addEvent: function() {
            if(this.event.name) {
                this.events.push(this.event);
                this.event = { name: '', description: '', date: '' };
            }
        }

    } // end of methods

});
```

I've tried to pass the event to the function and than delete that one with the slice function, I thought it was that code for deleting some data from the array. What is the best en cleanest way to delete data from the array with a simpleb button and onclick event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove specific item from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-specific-item-from-array)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You're using `splice` in a wrong way.

The overloads are:

> array.splice(start)
>
> array.splice(start, deleteCount)
>
> array.splice(start, deleteCount, itemForInsertAfterDeletion1, itemForInsertAfterDeletion2, ...)

Start means the index that you want to start, not the element you want to remove. And you should pass the second parameter `deleteCount` as 1, which means: "I want to delete 1 element starting at the index {start}".

So you better go with:

```
deleteEvent: function(event) {
  this.events.splice(this.events.indexOf(event), 1);
}
```

Also, you're using a parameter, so you access it directly, not with  `this.event`.

But in this way you will look up unnecessary for the `indexOf` in every delete, for solving this you can define the `index` variable at your `v-for`, and then pass it instead of the event object.

That is:

```
v-for="(event, index) in events"
...

<button ... @click="deleteEvent(index)"
```

And:

```
deleteEvent: function(index) {
  this.events.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I already thought that I was using splice wrong. Can you tell me what the difference is between splice and slice? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Basically, sPlice modifies the original array, while slice creates a new array. More info here: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/javascript-splice-vs-slice/

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues, thanks for this one '_you can define the index variable at your `v-for`_' :) I love SO because of such gems.

Comment: @ Edmundo Rodrigues Thanks. It was really nice. I was just deleting with the index instead the index of object. thanks a lot

Comment: i think this is not a right answer for vue.js. you can use $delete method.Only in 2.2.0+: Also works with Array + index.

Answer (score 108):

You can also use .$delete:

```
remove (index) {
 this.$delete(this.finds, index)
}
```

sources:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete
- https://medium.com/vuejs-tips/tip-3-deleting-array-index-in-vue-js-8cc31d7214bf

Comment: This is the right way since let the Vue knows about the news.

Comment: why does it say in the documentation "you should rarely need to use it", is it good practice?

Comment: @Notflip: usually you will just replace the array as a whole.

Comment: This solution worked for me whereas the slice(index, 1) did nothing.

Comment: @Roberto slice and splice are different :)

Answer (score 58):

Don't forget to bind **key** attribute otherwise always **last** item will be deleted

Correct way to delete selected item from array:

**Template**

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
  <input v-model="item.value">
   <button @click="deleteItem(index)">
  delete
</button>
```

**script**

```
deleteItem(index) {
  this.items.splice(index, 1); \\OR   this.$delete(this.items,index)
 \\both will do the same
}
```

Comment: This should really be the selected answer.  I was wondering why neither of the options (splice or $delete) were working, and it turns out I just didn't have a proper key set.

Comment: Well it definitely deleted, something, but just started doing weird things when the binding was not yet in place.

Comment: I spent 4 hours wondering why the last element was always deleted.
Thank you for this!

Comment: We have noticed that you must not use the loop index as :key value.

E.g. `<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">` didn't work.

Comment: @HendrikPilz I have used item.id in key

Comment: I know, I just left that notice here as we used the index by mistake and it took a while to spot the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can delete item through id

```
<button @click="deleteEvent(event.id)">Delete</button>
```

Inside your JS code

```
deleteEvent(id){
  this.events = this.events.filter((e)=>e.id !== id )
}
```

Vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also trigger view updates. [Click here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array) for more details.

You might think this will cause Vue to throw away the existing DOM and re-render the entire list - luckily, that is not the case.

Comment: for vue 3 its bad. You convert Proxy{[items]} to [Proxy{item},Proxy{item}]

Answer (score 6):

It is even funnier when you are doing it with inputs, because they should be bound. If you are interested in how to do it in Vue2 with options to insert and delete, please see an example:

please have a look an [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene82/mjnyLm0q/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finds: [] 
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
      this.finds.push({ value: 'def' });
    },
    deleteFind: function (index) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(this.finds);
      this.finds.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Finds</h1>
  <div v-for="(find, index) in finds">
    <input v-model="find.value">
    <button @click="deleteFind(index)">
      delete
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="addFind">
    New Find
  </button>
  
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use indexOf to get the current index from the array

```
remove: function (event){
      this.events.splice(this.events.indexOf(event),1);
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just omit the method all together like:

```
v-for="(event, index) in events"
...
<button ... @click="$delete(events, index)">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-btn color="info" @click="eliminarTarea(item.id)">Eliminar</v-btn>
```

And for your JS:

```
this.listaTareas = this.listaTareas.filter(i=>i.id != id)
```

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as others and not better than others. So it's not worthy to post this.

Comment: @foxiris Don't discourage users to post their answers. If you don't find this solution helpful then let it go.

Comment: for vue 3 its bad. You convert Proxy{[items]} to [Proxy{item},Proxy{item}]

Answer (score 0):

> Splice is the best to remove element from specific index. The given
>   example is tested on console.

```
card = [1, 2, 3, 4];
card.splice(1,1);  // [2]
card   // (3) [1, 3, 4]
splice(startingIndex, totalNumberOfElements)
```

> startingIndex start from 0.