# Cannot remove element from array of components (slice, Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'am trying to implements dynamic adding and removing components in Vue.js.

There is a problem with slice method, basically it should remove element from array by passed index. To mutate an array i use **slice(i,1)** .

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046491/7106148) answer, modifying array in this way should help me, but is's not working.

What i am doing wrong?

Here is my code and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Halws/pen/XqRPoW):

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addNewComp">add new component</button>
  <template  v-for="(comp,index) in arr">
    <component 
     :is="comp"
     :index="index"
     @remove-comp="removeComp(index)"
     ></component>
  </template>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template " id="compTemplate"> 
  <h1> I am a component {{index}} 
  <button v-on:click="$emit('remove-comp')">X</button>
  </h1>
</script>
```

---

```
 const newComp = Vue.component("newComp",{
  template:"#compTemplate",
  props:['index']
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    arr:[newComp]
  },
  methods:{
    addNewComp:function(){
      this.arr.push(newComp);
        console.log(this.arr);
    },
    removeComp:function(i){
      console.log(i);
       this.arr.slice(i,1);
       console.log(this.arr);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 const newComp = Vue.component("newComp",{
  template:"#compTemplate",
  props:['index']
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    arr:[newComp]
  },
  methods:{
    addNewComp:function(){
      this.arr.push(newComp);
    },
    removeComp:function(i, a){
      console.log('i', i, a, typeof i);
      this.arr.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addNewComp">add new component</button>
  <template  v-for="(comp,index) in arr">
    <component 
     :is="comp"
     :index="index"
     @remove-comp="removeComp(index, 100+index)"
      :key="`${index}`"
     ></component>
  </template>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template " id="compTemplate"> 
  <h1> I am a component {{index}} 
  <button v-on:click="$emit('remove-comp')">X</button>
  </h1>
</script>
```

I read this before its to do with Vue and reactive states.
`.slice()` is non-reactive so it returns a copy of the data without altering the original( i.e. non-reactive).
Use the `.splice()` which is reactive or even better look at the `.filter()` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array)

Comment: It's working, but now it remove only last item from array. Why this could happen?

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks

Comment: @NazarKotsyuba no thats not right i removed the comment. All that does is replaces the element with the third parameter dont do that. So i have had a mess around with the code it doesnt just remove the end. the `.splice(i,1)` works but its just everything is reactive so say if you have a array size 0-9 and remove the index 2, the 10th element becomes the 9th. Its reactive so when you remove the element from the array all integers above it get -1. If you understand

Comment: Look at the snippet above and look at the `a` parameter in the log

Comment: Aha, so to summarize: it's remove correct component, but because of reactivity all next components change their numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the **slice** method instead of the **splice** one as mentioned in the link you provided.

```
deleteEvent: function(index) {
  this.events.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i just noticed it too.. Thank you)