# How delete an item using vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I just started learning vuex and can`t delete item. I can delete item directly in the component.

```
deleteCar (cars, id) {
        this.$http.delete('http://localhost:3000/cars/' + cars.id)
          .then(() => {              
              this.cars.splice(id, 1)
          })
      }
```

In vuex i have:

```
state: {
    car: {},
    cars: []
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_CAR (state, car) {
      state.car = car
    },
    GET_CARS (state, cars) {
      state.cars = cars
    }

  },
  actions: {
    createCar({commit}, car) {
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/cars', car)
        .then(() => {
          commit('ADD_CAR', car)
        })
    },

    loadCars({commit}) {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/cars')
        .then(res => {
            const cars = res.data
            commit('GET_CARS', cars)
        })
    }
  }
```

Code in component where i wanna delete item:

```
<div class="card mb-3" v-for="(car, i) in cars" :key="i">
      <div class="card-header">
      Cars name: {{ car.carName }}
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Country: {{ car.country }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Year of manufacture: {{ car.carYear }}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-5" @click="deleteCar(car, i)">Delete Car</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I can add car and get cars. But can`t delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an item from an array in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046332/how-to-remove-an-item-from-an-array-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to commit a mutation to delete the car

Here is your method

```
deleteCar (cars, id) {
    this.$http.delete('http://localhost:3000/cars/' + cars.id)
        .then(() => {              
              this.cars.splice(id, 1);
        });
}
```

Instead of `deleteCar(cars, id)` you will want to change it to `deleteCars({commit}, id)`

So your action would be

```
deleteCar ({commit}, id) {
    this.$http.delete('http://localhost:3000/cars/' + id)
        .then(() => {              
             commit('DELETE_CAR', id);
        });
}
```

And you have a mutation `DELETE_CAR`

```
DELETE_CAR(state, id){
    index = state.cars.findIndex(car => car.id == id);
    state.cars.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: In the mutation DELETE_CAR I would put an if statement after that index because if a car is not found findIndex returns -1 which splice will use to remove elements from the end of the array - likely not the effect you want.

Answer (score 6):

A simplified answer for clarity.

in the template:

```
<button @click="deleteCar(car)">Delete Car</button>
```

method in the component:

```
 deleteCar(car) {
    this.$store.commit('DELETE_CAR', car);
 }
```

mutation in the store:

```
 DELETE_CAR(state, car) {
    var index = state.cars.findIndex(c => c.id == car.id);
    state.cars.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using Axios with Vue, so your request `.delete` requesst that delete already but in `.then` you should do something not related to delete or splice,

```
     deleteCar (cars) {
        this.$http
          .delete('http://localhost:3000/cars/' + cars.id', { data: payload })
          .then(
            //here write what you want after delete
            res => console.log(res);
          )
      }
```

in `.then` you do what you need after delete because of `.delete` request already deleted that part from your JSON data

Comment: I wanna just to delete item from array. But wanna do this with axios. I can get data with axios, can post. But have problem with delete