# Deleting an item in the store Vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I would like to delete an item that is located in my store.
I saw this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686164/11984242 which seems to be what I'm looking for BUT I have another "level" in my object so I don't know how to delete an element from a sub-level.

The structure of my data.

```js
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'My customer one',
    projects: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'name',
            tests: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'name test'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'name test 2'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'other name'
        }
    ]
}
```

So I see how to delete a project with the link above. But how to delete one row of tests ?

I do this in my vue :

```js
this.$store.commit("deleteTest", this.idProject, e)
```

And this in my store :

```js
deleteTest(state, {data, e}) {
    const allTestsOfProject = state.listProjects.projects.find(p => p.id === data)
    console.log("all", allTestsOfProject)
    const oneTest = allTestsOfProject.studies.find(q => q.id === e)
    console.log("one test", oneTest)
    //state.listProjects.projects.splice(oneTest, 1)
  }
```

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: can you add the error occured when running your solution

Comment: No error : this code deleted the entire project instead just the test item with id 1 for example.

Comment: does `console.log(oneTest)` work fine? does it console the right test

Comment: I think I did not do well: I had tried directly in my template Vue; I had my good data in my console log.
    But when I passed my function in the store, it doesn't work anymore. I think I have problems with the payload data because it doesn't recognize anything anymore. I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: please try: `allTestsOfProject.tests.splice(oneTest, 1)`

Comment: Does not work : the console.log("all", allTestsOfProject) render "undefined" ... I think he does not take my payload

Comment: change `this.$store.commit("deleteTest", this.idProject, e)` to `this.$store.commit("deleteTest", {data: this.idProject, e})`

Comment: I change with this : this.$store.commit("deleteStudie", {data : this.idProject, test :e}) and in my store deleteStudie(state, {data, test}) { ... 
So know, my two console.log have the good data. 

But when I click to delete, it is always the first Test how is deleted instead of the test with the good ID 
allStudieOfProject.studies.splice(oneStudie, 1)

Comment: now use this `allTestsOfProject.tests.splice(oneTest, 1)`

Comment: Yah now it is always the first test and not the test with the good id who is deleted ... :(

Comment: so `oneTest` is not the test which you want to delete

Comment: When I log "oneTest" it is the good one ... But when I splice, it 's not I don't understand. It is always the first of the list...

Comment: change `find` into `findIndex` so it'll be `allTestsOfProject.studies.findIndex (q => q.id === e)`

Comment: Oh my god it's so cool ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome, I'll post the answer. please accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Have two problem with your code:

### First Problem

`commit` function takes only 2 params:

1. commit name  ( as String )
2. Payload Pbject

so if you want to pass multiple props you should pass them as an object

```js
this.$store.commit("deleteTest", this.idProject, e) // WON'T WORK
this.$store.commit("deleteTest", {data: this.idProject, e}) // WILL WORK
```

now you can call `deleteTest(state, {data, e})`

### Second Problem

you should get the **INDEX** of tests object not the **OBJECT** itself

```js
const oneTest = allTestsOfProject.studies.find(q => q.id === e) // WON'T WORK
const oneTest = allTestsOfProject.studies.findIndex(q => q.id === e) // WILL WORK
```

now you can call: `allTestsOfProject.studies.findIndex (q => q.id === e)` to delete your test