# Removing an object from array in Vue.js - throws Property of method is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 3 files: `App`, `BlogList`, `BlogItem`.
I want to allow the user to delete the `post` if she/he wants to. I am using splice but for some reason, I get this error:

> *Property or method "removePost" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.*

Here are the code snippets(BlogList is included in the App and also consists of many BlogItems):

**App:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header />
    <PostList v-bind:posts="posts" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Header from ...
import PostList from ...

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
    PostList,
  },
data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**BlogList:**

```
<template>
<div class="blog-list">
    <div v-for="(post,index) in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">
      <PostItem v-bind:post="[post,index]" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import PostItem from ...

export default {
  name: "PostList",
  components: {
    PostItem
  },
  props: ["posts"],
  methods: {
    removePost: function(index) {
      this.$delete(this.posts, index);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**BlogItem:**

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post-text">{{post.data.title}}</div>
      <button class="btn-remove" @click="removePost(index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PostItem",
  props: ["post"]
};
</script>
```

I am still fairly new to Vue and passing the data between the components seems is a challenge. I tried declaring the function in BlogList as it is where I put my v-for but I cannot fetch the index of the blog post's clicked(and I believe that is what causes issues). I'm including only the necessary bits of code and I am aware that a similar question has been asked already ([How to remove an item from an array in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046332/how-to-remove-an-item-from-an-array-in-vue-js)) but in my case, I want to use 3 separate components instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined removePost in the `BlogList`, but not in the `BlogItem` component, that is why it throws an error. Also, there is no index within the `BlogItem` component's scope. In your scenario, it would be best to either emit the event or use the `<slot>`.

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post-text">{{this.post.data.title}}</div>
      <button class="btn-remove" @click="removePost(this.index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PostItem",
  props: ["post", "index"],
  methods: {
    removePost(index){
     this.$emit('remove-post', index);

    }

  }
};
</script>
```

And then in the `PostList` component, catch the event within `created()` and call the parent's `removePost`:

```
<template>
<div class="blog-list">
    <div v-for="(post,index) in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">
      <PostItem v-bind:post="[post,index]" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import PostItem from ...

export default {
  name: "PostList",
  components: {
    PostItem
  },
  props: ["posts"],
  created(){
    this.$root.$on('remove-post', function(index){
      this.removePost(index);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    removePost: function(index) {
      this.$delete(this.posts, index);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Oh..okay! Thanks for that :). Does it mean I need to move that function to blogitem and then 'emit' the event or should I include the function in both files?

Comment: @priortt, I added an example of one way to do this