# How to delete items from an array in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a function called updateAnswer with multiple dynamic parameters.

```
        updateAnswer(key, answer, array = false) {
        if (array) {
            if(this.answers.contains.find(element => element === answer)) {

                //Delete item from array if already element already exists in this.answers.contains array.

            } else {
                Vue.set(this.answers, key, [...this.answers.contains, answer]);
            }

        } else {
            Vue.set(this.answers, key, answer);
        }
    },
```

I'd like to know how delete an item in the array if the value already exists in the array.

Comment: this.answers.contains = this.answers.contains.filter(element=> element !== answer)

Comment: refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046332/how-to-remove-an-item-from-an-array-in-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

You can use method called `splice`:

Just reference on your array and set values in the brackets the first is referenced on the position, the second is how many datas you want to splice/delete.

The function looks like this:

`this.array.splice(value, value)`

Lets see on an example - you have array `food= [apple, banana, strawberry]` than I'm using `this.food.splice(1,1)`..

my array looks now like this `food = [apple, strawberry]` - first value in my brackets are the position, the second one is the amount of "numbers" you want to delete.

Hopefully this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose each value in `this.answers.contains` is unique?

Anyways, if you just want to delete the item if already exists, I suggest `filter()`. It should look like below:

```
if(this.answers.contains.find(element => element === answer)) {
    this.answers.contains = this.answers.contains.filter(c => c !== answer)
}
```

Also, the if condition `if(this.answers.contains.find(element => element === answer))` could also be replaced by `if(this.answers.contains.includes(answer))`

Hope that could help you.