# Deleting a Vue component dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I am trying to render certain components which are present in an array using **component** tag of Vue js.

```
<div v-for="(arr, index) in compArray">
    <component v-bind:is="arr.name" :key="arr.name+index" :index="index"></component>
</div>

data() {
  compArray: [{name: "Abc"}, {name: "Xyz"}]
}
```

I am able to add new elements to this compArray and which will increase the components that are rendered. But when i am deleting, there is an issue with UI (data). Like, if there are 3 components and all three are having data property **count**.

Suppose for first element rendered this count is 4, for second it is 5 and for third it is 2. Then if i delete the second element from the **compArray** using slice method, data shown is still 5. In ideal case it should be 2, since middle one has been deleted.

What can be the issue behind this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: it seems a :key="arr.uniqueKey" is missing for the v-for loop

Comment: No key also is given, sorry i missed that in the question @Kunukn

Comment: Have you tried this pattern? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52233910/815507  if that does not work, could you add a reproduceable example?