# How to Create Component on the fly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

First of all here is my structure

`CHILD COMPONENT`

```
// HTML
<v-select
 v-bind:items="selectItems"
 v-model="selectedItemModel"
 label="Category"
 item-value="text"
></v-select>
<v-text-field
 label="Enter Value"
 type="number"
 v-model="compValModel"
></v-text-field>

// REMOVE BUTTON for deleting this component in render.
<v-btn icon>
  <v-icon>cancel</v-icon>
</v-btn>

// JS
props: {
 selectItems: {
  type: Array,
  required: true
 },
 selectedItem: {
  type: String
 },
 compVal: {
  type: Number
 },
}
data () {
 return {
  selectedItemModel: this.selectedItem,
  compValModel: this.compVal
 }
},
watch: {
 selectedItemModel(value) {
   this.$emit('selectedItemInput', value);
 },
 compValModel(value) {
   this.$emit('compValInput', value);
 }
}
```

`PARENT COMPONENT`

```
// HTML
<component 
 :selecItems="selectItems" 
 :selectedItem="selectOneItem" 
 :compVal="compOneVal"
 @selectedItemInput="selectOneItem = $event"
 @compValInput="compOneVal = $event"
></component>

// ADD BUTTON for adding the above component more.
<v-btn icon>
  <v-icon>cancel</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

### My Case

When i click on that plus button, it should create new component. and when i click on that REMOVE button from that component, it should delete that component.

Right now i have followed [this](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/359/duplicate-component-dynamically/2). The problem in this approach is, whenever a new component is created. the value of the exsisting dynamically created values got refereshed.

### My Question

1. Whats the good way to duplicate the component dynamically?
2. Since we are going to create components dynamically, how to create data values also dynamically?

Comment: but do you want an "array" of componenent like <user></user><user></user> [...] ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41374441/392102